# core data: save different types as the same attribute

Tags: core-data, swift2

I have a core data entity which has an attribute that can represent different types of values (int, double, date, string).

Would it lead to problems (e.g. loss of precision) somewhere down to line if I convert all these values to a String and then back?

```
@nsmanaged var storedType : Int
@nsmanaged var storedValue : String
var value: Any? {
{
 set {
  switch newValue
  {
  case is Int:
    self.storedValue = String(newValue)
    self.storedType = 0

  ...

  case is string
    self.storedValue = newValue
    self.storedType = 5
  }
 }
 get {
  switch newValue
  {
  case is 0:
    return Int(self.storedValue)

  ...

  case is 5:
    return self.storedValue
  }
 }
}
}
```

Comment: *"I have a core data entity which has an attribute that can represent different types of values (int, double, date, string)."* Excuse me, I'm going to have to go and lie down for a while in a dark room. In the meantime, why would you do such a thing?

Comment: The entity describes among other things the range in a datafile. The data file can be string, date, int, float or whatever custom format the user specifies. So either I have an abstract entity with a whole bunch of subentities or I convert the range values to a string. The user can change the format after creation of the entity. If I use subentities, I have to copy the other fields, remove the entity, create a new entity, set all the fields and make sure the UI is still behaving for just change two values: start & end. Using a relationship instead also requires several barely used subentities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I would think long and hard about the architecture first I agree there may be a case for this functionality and where else than SO should this question be asked*.

One option is to use the transformable property type. This type allows coreData to store any object that is NSCoding compliant (NSArray, NSDictionary etc.) and also NSString and NSNumber I believe.

Thus you can retrieve that object as the generic type (id in Objective-C, don't know the equivalent in swift) and then query it for type and cast it to whatever you need.

The downside of this approach is of course that you loose a lot of the coreData power in querying the store as the values you store as transformable attributes become more or less opaque to predicates and such. However it works fine for walking the core data structure with key paths.

*) I believe I read that the equivalent variant data type in VB is one of Joel Spolsky's contributions to that language...

Comment: Thanks for considering my question and your answer. Some of us are self-taught programmers who make/learn things as they go along and whose only help/place for guidance are sites like SO.

Comment: Same situation here - so completely agree. Today I am stuck on some architecture issue of my own and is procrastinating by writing on SO...

Comment: Doing something else helps to solve a problem. Like they say: sleep on it. ;)